# tomcat classes from previous run remains

Tags: java, tomcat6, high-availability

i am running an application which uses spring, hibernate, jsf, etc. the application also uses ha-jdbc to make the databases highly available. when the application is deployed for the first time, the app runs smoothly, but when it is un-deployed and deployed back, tomcat gives the following error:

The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed), but their
classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory
leak (use a profiler to confirm):

i am wondering how to get rid of this problem. any genius?

thanks in advance.

Comment: this is what happens when you dont stop yer threads

Answer (score 5):

use a profiler (visualvm would do), do a heap snapshot, find the lingering objects, find the reference chain, and ponder why they are still referenced.

or, just restart tomcat for each deployment.

Comment: thanks fr the reply, restarting is not an option. or may be the last option. but is there any way of cleaning the previous classes while tomcat undeploys

Comment: @user582862 - Yes, by fixing the memory leak in your app.

Comment: restarting should be the first option. why is it so important that it's the same server? just bring up a new server, and kill the old one.

Comment: i wish my supervisor understood that. he is insisting the application needs to keep on running so the server cannot be stopped.

Comment: anyhow let me know if there is any alternative way. by the way, whats the maximum number of hot-deployment? i think there was a limitation isnt it?

Comment: one of the reasons he thinks the app should stay on the server is because its for the medical sector and their usage cant be stopped. not sure, but i think even if you hot deploy, the app would still stop, what do you guys think?

Comment: start the new server before stopping the old server, then you always have a server running.