# How to fix bug Memory Leak in Tomcat server

Tags: java, deployment, memory-leaks, tomcat7

I have a problem about Memory Leak in Tomcat server.
When I undeploy and redeploy the error message war appeared as below:

> The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed), but their classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory leak (use a profiler to confirm): /myWebApplication

How can I fix it and deploy as normally
If anyone known that , please help me .
Thank you very much !

Comment: similar question ! ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565105/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-undeployment-memory-leaks-in-tomcat

Comment: Duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959042/tomcat-classes-from-previous-run-remains

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you implement a ServletContextListener and clean up any resources (e.g. threads, timers, singletons, hibernate) that may still be active or referenced at the time that contextDestroyed() is called.